# Passing PHP variable to Modal Window in same page

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I am stuck with modal window. My modal window is on same page which I put in `<div>`, this modal window will popup when  user click on a 'Reply Message' text.

```
while (($i < $num3b)&&($i < ($start+$perpage))) {
$tododetail_id=mysql_result($result3b,$i,"tododetail_id");
$comment=formatUrlsInText(mysql_result($result3b,$i,"comment"));
$staff_name=mysql_result($result3b,$i,"staff_name");
echo "<tr><td><span><font color='#5858FA'>" . $staff_name . nl2br($comment) . "</font>
<span style='float:right' id='create-user'>Reply Message</span>";
```

$i++;}

And Modal Window will appear using below code, i want to pass `$staff_name` and `$comment` so that it will appear in modal window. but i don't know how to call and pass those variables

```
  $(function() {
    var repmsg = $( "#repmsg" );

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 280,
      width: 660,
      modal: true
    });

    $( '[id^="create-user"]')
       .click(function() {
          $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
```

Here my modal window code

```
<div id="dialog-form">
  <p class="validateTips"><!--show php variable ($staff_name)--></p>
  <form>
  <fieldset>
   <textarea class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" name='repmsg' cols='100' rows='8' tabindex='1004'></textarea><br/>
   <span id="quote" style="float:left">Requote</span>
   <span style='float:right' id='button'>
    <span id="add" class="button_form" style="cursor:pointer;">Add</span>
    <span id="cancel" class="button_form" style="cursor:pointer;">Cancel</span>
   </span>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
</div>
```

Hopefully you can understand my statement. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael I appreciate that you are trying to help by editing, but one-letter edits to the title aren't really all that useful. A whole lot of people would prefer that you only make suggested edits that address _all_ the issues in the post, or don't suggest an edit at all if a single typo is the only problem.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat What are "suggested edits"? Usually I edit bad formatted code to well formatted code cause I hate to see bad code styling, makes it hard to read for everyone! Of course I also improve content of questions and answers. However, yesterday I was searching for an answer, but I could not find it because of a typo in the title (found it later when I made the typo myself). So I decided to fix some typos in titles. It's fast reputation and the main reason I did this is that it helps search engines to find question/answers. That's a good point even though it's not a mayor improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you create several span with the same id. An id must be unique in a html page.

You must create different ids. This will also allow you to get the data with jquery.

Also think about putting your staff name in a separate div or span. This will ease accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

In below part, just put the staffname variable:

```
<p class="validateTips"><?php echo $staff_name; ?></p>
```

This staffname will be shown when dialog opened

Comment: my data for $staff_name is gained from looping process.